# Can't build recovery image with AOSP 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build the recovery.img for AOSP 4.2.2 with the following commands:

```
cd myandroidsrc
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch
make recoveryimage -j8
```

But I keep running into the following error:

```
find: `src': No such file or directory
...
a lot of "PRODUCT_COPY_FILES /frameworkds/base/data/.. .ogg ignored" messages
...   
cp -f /boot.img /device/myvendor/mydevice/boot/
cp: cannot stat `/boot.img': No such file or directory
make: *** [out/target/product/mydevice/boot.img] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/mydevice/boot.img'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I also tried to build the boot image with:

```
make bootimage
```

But this also results in the same error like @ the make recoveryimage call. Am I missing some make call here or is my file structure wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using prebuilt boot.img if yes check its path properly.                   cp -f /boot.img /device/myvendor/mydevice/boot/
As you can see above the root of device tree should have boot.img which is being copied.

Comment: If you have to use your new source you can modify your device tree to point to kernel source or build the modified one and use it as a prebuilt image.